# ERPNext - How to see iconic dashboard

Tags: erpnext

I have hosted free trial of cloud ERPNext and followed all the tutorial to set basic configuration. As i am very new to this system, How can I see dashboad like below?[image]

As I am learning this system and documentation is heavy... Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This dashboard view was in ERPNext11, now it has upgraded to ERPNext12.

https://discuss.erpnext.com/t/version-12-killing-the-iconic-desktop/44998